# Why list eigenvectors as basis of eigenspace versus as a single, representative vector?

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Specifically, suppose $\lambda_1$ is an eigenvalue of the matrix $A$, and that it has multiplicity of 2.

Also suppose that the eigenspace corresponding to $\lambda_1$ consists solely of vectors of the form 
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
{\alpha/2+\beta\\\alpha\\\beta}
\end{pmatrix}
=
\alpha\begin{pmatrix}
{\frac12\\1\\0}
\end{pmatrix}
+\beta\begin{pmatrix}
{1\\0\\1}
\end{pmatrix}
$$
In this case I believe we would call $\begin{pmatrix}
{1\\0\\1}
\end{pmatrix}$ and $\begin{pmatrix}
{\frac12\\1\\0}
\end{pmatrix}$

eigenvectors corresponding to the eigenvalue $\lambda_1$

> Since any vector, $v$, of the form $v=\begin{pmatrix}
> {\alpha/2+\beta\\\alpha\\\beta}
> \end{pmatrix}$ satisfies $Av=\lambda_1 v$ how come the basis vectors are the eigenvectors?
>
> **More specifically, I am wondering if** can I just say that "the eigenvectors corresponding to eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ are all vectors of the form $v=\begin{pmatrix}
> {\alpha/2+\beta\\\alpha\\\beta}
> \end{pmatrix}$?

Is it that both approaches are okay, but using vectors that form a basis is more informative (for example giving info about dimension of the eigenspace)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All nonzero vectors $x$ satisfying $A x = \lambda x$ are eigenvectors. 
Not just the basis vectors.  It's just that a convenient way to specify a
vector space is to list a basis for it.

Comment: Thank you very much. Thats exactly what I was wondering.